# Neested loops in pandas python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have two DataFrames One with many rows and another one with a few rows and I need to merge these two Dataframes according some conditions (in strings). I used nested loops in Pandas like this:

```
density = []

for row in df.itertuples():
    for row1 in df2.itertuples():
        if(row['a'].find(row1['b']))>0:
            density.append(row1['c'])
```

But I receive the error message:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It would be helpful to see what these dataframes look like.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `df` and `df2`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        a=['abcd', 'stk', 'shij', 'dfffedeffj', 'abcdefghijk'],
    ))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        b=['abc', 'hij', 'def'],
        c=[1, 2, 3]
    ))
```

You can produce decent-ish speed with `get_value` and `set_value`.  And I'd store the values in a dataframe

```
density = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=df2.index)

for i in df.index:
    for j in df2.index:
        a = df.get_value(i, 'a')
        b = df2.get_value(j, 'b')
        if a.find(b) >= 0:
            density.set_value(i, j, df2.get_value(j, 'c'))

print(density)

     0    1    2
0    1  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN    2  NaN
3  NaN  NaN    3
4    1    2    3
```

You can also use a composite `numpy` `str` functions

```
t = df2.b.apply(lambda x: df.a.str.contains(x)).values

c = df2.c.values[:, None]

density = pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(t, np.hstack([c] * t.shape[1]), np.nan).T,
    df.index, df2.index)
```

Answer (score 1):

The method DataFrame.itertuples returns namedtuples and to access the values in a namedtuple you have to use the dot notation.

```
density = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    for row1 in df2.itertuples():
        if row.a.find(row1.b) > 0:
            density.append(row1.c)
```

Nevertheless, this does not produce a merge of the two DataFrames.